# Bayesian Structural Time Series modeling using BSTS

Tags: r, time-series, bayesian

Has anyone attempted to set up a model using the R BSTS package that mimics the methodology that Facebook Prophet uses? If so what are the components and parameters?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know FB Prophet isn't a BSTS model and operates in quite a different manner. See this page for more info https://content.nexosis.com/blog/methods-of-demand-forecasting-bsts-prophet